# L'orthographe de la prononciation phonétique [ka/ʀe/mɑ̃]

Tags: orthographe, phonétique

Je viens de regarder une vidéo, et il y a un mot que je *sais* que je connais, mais je n'arrive pas à le trouver dans le dictionnaire.

L'orthographe phonétique (je crois) est ainsi: `[ka/ʀe/mɑ̃]` (peut-être que je me trompe)

Comment est-il écrit? On peut l'entendre dans cette scène de la vidéo [*Les aventures hipsters de Norman*](http://youtu.be/pYVW0I-NnDc?t=1m18s) sur Youtube.

Comment: Sur le [dictionnaire en ligne TLFi](http://atilf.atilf.fr), vous pouvez [**rechercher un mot par prononciation phonétique**](http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv4/showps.exe?p=combi.htm) : en sélectionnant les sons K-A-R-É-M-AN, on obtient directement le mot _carrément_. Utile pour les prochaines fois ! ;-)

Comment: Chouette! Je l'utiliserai la prochaine fois, merci!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ce moment de la vidéo le mot "carrément" `[ka.ʁe.mɑ̃]` est utilisé plusieurs fois.

Comment: Ah voilà, merci :) j'essayais trouver ce mot dans le dictionnaire mais bon, je ne savais pas comment l'écrire donc déjà c'est un peu difficile. Merci!